# Convert IEX Finance API data to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, api, dataframe, url

I want to pull data from the IEX finance api and put it into a pandas dataframe but I don't know the correct code.  Can someone help?

URL call for the api = 
https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/chart/1d?chartInterval=5

I tried the below but it doesn't work

```
import pandas as pd
api_call = 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/chart/1d?chartInterval=5' 
price = pd.read_csv(api_call)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is in **JSON** format. To load into dataframe you have to call `read_json` function.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/chart/1d?chartInterval=5")
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!